# Type errors using Apollo Client in React Native typescript project

Tags: react-native, graphql, apollo

I am trying to use Apollo Client in my React Native project. I tried to generate types from the graphql API based on the official tutorial: `https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/development-testing/static-typing/`

The problem is that I am using the `gql` function which returns `unknown`. And these make problems in the `useQuery` and `useMutation` hooks.

A defined mutation (this is working in Apollo playground):

```
export const registerMutation = gql(`
  mutation Register($email: String!, $password: String!, $companyName: String) {
    register(data:{email: $email, password: $password, companyName: $companyName}){
      name
      email
      profileImage
    }
  }
`);
```

Usage of the mutation:

```
const [register] = useMutation(registerMutation);
```

The error I am getting from useMutation hook: `Argument of type 'unknown' is not assignable to parameter of type 'DocumentNode | TypedDocumentNode<any, OperationVariables>'.`

Answer (score 3):

I was also getting the same error I resolved it by assigning a type to the mutation i.e. a type can be assigned to the `registerMutation` where it is defined.

For example,

```
import { TypedDocumentNode, gql } from "@apollo/client";
import {
  MutationTokenAuthArgs,
  ObtainJsonWebToken,
} from "src/__generated__/graphql";

export const FETCH_TOKEN: TypedDocumentNode<
  ObtainJsonWebToken,
  MutationTokenAuthArgs
> = gql`
  mutation tokenAuth($email: String!, $password: String!) {
    tokenAuth(email: $email, password: $password) {
      refreshExpiresIn
      token
    }
  }
`;
```

Notice I have used gql from the @apollo/client and not the one that was generated by codegen and the types `MutationTokenAuthArgs`, `ObtainJsonWebToken` were generated by the graphql codegen. I searched them using the mutation name in my case `tokenAuth` in the folder provided in `codegen.ts` under the `generates` key.

Link for the source:

- [Using TypedDocumentNode](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/development-testing/static-typing#using-typeddocumentnode)
- [Using typescript](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/development-testing/static-typing/)

Comment: I had this problem with only 1 mutation after some dependency updates. In my case, importing `gql` from `@apollo/client` for that mutation, instead of the one from `generated` folder, fixed the issue. I would consider this a temporary fix for my case though.